# Illegal instruction (core dumped) -Tensorflow GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed Tensorflow-GPU version 1.9.0 and simple tensorflow import statement gives exception "Illegal instruction (core dumped)". If I downgrade tensorflow version to 1.5.0, it works fine. How to fix this issue for higher version as I need to work with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with [v1.5.1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/v1.5.1) on Linux and [v1.6.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/v1.6.0) on other platforms, the official TensorFlow distribution is compiled with [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) instructions, meaning that older CPUs will not work with it (you can look up model compatibility, but it does not have to be an ancient CPU, it happened to me on an old Core i7).

If you want to use official releases, the only solution is to switch to a different hardware or to stick to the older version. There have been [requests for support for older CPUs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18689) (and some people have uploaded their own [build for a particular configuration](https://github.com/maxhgerlach/tensorflow-1.8.0-ubuntu16.04-py27-no_avx-xeon_x5650), if it works for you and you trust it), but the general answer is that if you need specific support for your platform you can always build it yourself, disabling AVX optimizations (see the [installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)).