# TensorFlow 2.0 Model to an Arm_v7 (32-bit) Device

Tags: tensorflow, arm, tensorflow2.0

First  time trying  to do this so bear with me.

I have trained a model on my Linux Box (x86_64) using a TitanX and am trying to deploy the model to an Arm_v7 device.
I have ran into multiple roadblocks but the one I can't over come is that when I run the code on the Arm_v7 device i get the following (tried with regular tensorflow and tflite):

o   Output: Illegal Instruction

I did some digging and this is due to to TensorFlow  2.x using AVX instructions with Arm_v7 doesn't support. [Illegal instruction (core dumped) -Tensorflow GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391543/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-tensorflow-gpu)

Can you do this? Can you train a model on a new x86_64 and deploy it to a Arm_v7? Are there parameters I can set during training to make this work? We can't train on the deployed unit because it will be to slow.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by arm7 do you mean armv7 (very different) and what do you mean by arm32?  I assume you mean armv7, would be better to know the specific core or even better the chip since the arm is only a small part of the chip.

Comment: i meant Arm_v7 (which is a 32 bit system). thanks for catching that. been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not an expert in Arm7's, and if I'm wrong please let me know, I do not think that It will be possible to run the Code you wrote on a 64-bit Operating system on a 32-bit one. Also, considering the post you shared in your question (Illegal instruction (core dumped) -Tensorflow GPU), the only solution is to get other hardware. But again, I could be wrong with this, but to the BEST of my knowledge this is not possible.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. If this is the case I would think it is really limiting. Seems like you have to train and infer on the same architecture family. I would have thought it would have been agnostic to the training arch since I thought you were just passing the model and weights.